# Performance issue on IBM RFT in chrome

Tags: rft

I am using IBM RFT scripts for automation testing. I am facing one performance issue in chrome. while doing playback in google chrome it is taking 4 min per each click. i am new to this. can any one please help me.

Comment: What are the recognition score of your objects? If the score is high RFT waits (up to 2 minutes if I remember correctly) for each object before clicking. Maybe in Chrome your website gets a different HTML or elements may have a different id/class.

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite some time this question was asked, however with RFT 8.6.0.6 and Chrome 46 and above, this problem should not be seen.